# Image doesn't move on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, input, keyboard

I'm new. I was trying to move an image but it just doesn't, I don't know where is the problem. I checked some topics but it didn't work., well here's my code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var bgImage = new Image();
  var player = new Image();
  var x = 50;
      var y = 50;
// We draw the background
  bgImage.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
  };
  bgImage.src ='images/bg.png';
// We draw the player
player.onload = function(){
context.drawImage(player, x, y);
};
player.src = "images/player.png";
addEventListener("keypress", move,true);
function move(e){
if (e.keyCode == 39){
x += 2;
}
if (e.keyCode == 37){
x -= 4;
}
if (e.keyCode == 38){
y -= 4;
}
if (e.keyCode == 40){
y += 4;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the concept of the thing here, canvas is not dynamic by itself, it only provides you with the ability to draw static image frames. Therefore, the animation and interaction is possible, but it has to be entirely coded by yourself.

Any animation effect is given through the drawing of a continuous series of static frames over one another. Each frame will graphicaly represent a slight change in position/form/color of one or various objects within the scene.

It becomes clear you'd have to setup a loop chain where any change made to properties of an object in the scene would be reflected in the image frame which is currently on screen.

So it's not enough to change the value of your `x` and `y` variables, because they have been used only once in your code, to draw the first frame, then, they are used nowhere. There is nothing being drawn after the first frame. That one static image you created will remain forever on the screen, you can't expect animation out of a single static image.

Fix-wise, it's firstly necessary to setup a loading scheme for your image resources, since you need more than one. Because their loading is asynchronous AND out of order (they do not load respecting the order they were created).

After everything is loaded, you can choose to either fire a continuous loop, which will draw another frame regardless of wheter any change has actually been made to anything on the screen (this is the standard way for making animations, in more complex applications, it will allow you to keep control of animation time)

Or, since your code is simple enough, you could choose to draw another frame when, and only when, the position of your object has been changed. Something like this

```
addEventListener("keypress", move,true);
function move(e)
{
    //... key handling stuff

    redraw(); // Drawing the next, modified, frame
}

function redraw()
{
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    context.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
    context.drawImage(player, x, y);
}
```

Comment: In fact i created a main loop that contains a draw function and update function that updates x and y coords every time I press a key

Comment: That's because I've figured out the code after I posted the question